# Kafka Stream with Java: Send the same object to multiple topics if it matches certain criteria

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

**Task**: there is a Kafka-topic we listen to. After processing we want to see messages in three different output topics whereas *the same message might go to several output topics*. How to model a such demultiplexer with Kafka-Streams?

I have tried to use:

```
        Map<String, KStream<String, String>> branches = builder
                .stream("input", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .transform(supplier1, "TRANSIT_STORE_NAME")
                .split(Named.as("prepare_data"))
                .branch((k, v) -> v != null && v.contains("xyz"), Branched.as("xyz"))
                .branch((k, v) -> v != null && v.contains("abc"), Branched.as("abc"))
                .noDefaultBranch();
        branches.get("prepare_dataxyz")
                .transform(supplier2)
                .to("output.xyz");
        branches.get("prepare_dataabc")
                .transform(supplier2)
                .to("output.abc");
```

So a record having value = *"abcxyz_blabla"* should theoretically go to the topic "output.xyz" **and** to the topic "output.abc".

But *branch()* acts in the way that the messages go to the first appropriate branch/topic.
The same effect has *filter()*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use just one `String#contains`, then.

```
.branch((k, v) -> v != null && v.contains("abc") && v.contains("xyz"), Branched.as("both"))
```

Comment: OK, thanx :), and then I should do something like this, right? =>

branches.get("prepare_databoth")
                .transform(supplier2)
                .to("output.abc")
                .to("output.xyz");

Comment: Or `.through("output.abc").to("output.xyz")`